# Shipping multi-container Docker app

Tags: web-applications, docker, containers

I've recently been using Docker and researching about how one might ship a dockerized application. If everything was stored in one container (ex: Tomcat, webapp, MySql), it would seem easy to send someone one .tar of the image for them to run. However, most people have been saying to separate your database from your application. So if I wanted to ship an application that required multiple containers, what would be the best method to do so?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, it is a reasonable question. Although, you should probably not ship a single tar but instead find a way to reference which version of multiple images to pull from the registry.

Answer (score 2):

Check out docker compose. It is designed to specify, spin up, and link multiple containers together.

He is an example config listed on the front page:

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
  links:
   - redis
redis:
  image: redis
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/